# JQuery .is(':hover') not working correctly in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, hover, onmouseout

I am having a problem with a popup div in IE9 with the following code:

```
<li id="info001" class="listInfo" onmouseover="ShowPreview(this);" onmouseout="HidePreview();">
```

and my HidePreview checks to make sure the mouse isn't over the listItem or the preview itself, like this:

```
function HidePreview() {
    if (!($('#thePreview').is(':hover') || $('#info001').is(':hover'))) {
        $('#thePreview').hide();
    }
}
```

This works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE9 the preview starts flickering as I move over both the listItem and the preview, and then as I move over the preview alone, it gets hidden.

Is there any way to avoid this?

EDIT: For clarity, the thePreview div overlaps the info001 li enough to easily move the mouse between them.

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/ControlFreak/QQsGS/

Comment: I don't think that `:hover` is a valid jQuery selector. It doesn't appear in their [docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: You should really be using the jQuery event handlers for this instead of the html onmouse*="" handlers

Comment: @PatBurke I don't disagree with you. I was creating the ListItems dynamically and it was easier to put the handlers there. However, it should work either way.

Comment: @OneTrickPony it does work fine in Chrome and FireFox, so I'm guessing it's valid. I don't remember where I found it, but it was almost certainly here somewhere.

Comment: True, if you use .on() you can achieve dynamic event handlers as well.

Comment: In jquery 1.9, they removed *:hover*.  See here: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#hover-pseudo-event

Comment: @Dom Thanks, if they removed it I'll find another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing something like this instead:

```
var $thePreview = $("#thePreview");

$(".listInfo").hover(
    function () {
        $thePreview.show();
    },
    function () {
        $thePreview.hide();
    }
);
```

[Working example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htmled/fg6H8/).

You can still use that code, you just need to change the pseudo-event from hover to mouseenter mouseleave (if you're running 1.9+). See this for more info: jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#hover-pseudo-event

Comment: I guess it's not clear in my example, but the preview overlaps the ListItem, and if the cursor is over either one the preview stays up, similar to a popup menu. The preview does have clickable elements on it, so this is required.

Comment: Added jsFiddle to original message

Comment: I noticed you included jQuery 1.7.2 in your jsFiddle. Is this the exact same version of jQuery you're running on your site?

Comment: I am using 1.7.1 on my site, which is what comes with Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Instead of using that div outside of the ul, is there anyway you can use a span tag inside of each li with the class name "preview"?

Comment: I believe that the logic with hover I am doing that does work in Chrome and FF is actually no longer supported, so I am going to try to find a different way to handle this without using it.

Comment: You can still use that code, you just need to change the pseudo-event from hover to mouseenter mouseleave (if you're running 1.9+). See this for more info: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#hover-pseudo-event

Comment: Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to replace .is(:hover) with either of those to get the same behavior. It's not a complete loss though, I just need to work around it with a few tracking variables, but thanks for all the help! If you add an answer referencing that link I will mark it as answered.

Comment: I've added the link to my answer above.